# How to print decimal variable in perl

Tags: perl

Below is my decimal variable:

```
my $variable = 1.0;
```

When I try to print the variable,

```
print "$variable\n";
```

I got 1.0.

But, if I pass the same to a function:

```
&printvariable("$variable\n");

sub  printvariable()
{
    print "My variable is: @_";
}
```

Now, it is printing as, `My variable is: 1`

Why is this decimal value getting rounded off in the function? Is there a way to print the value as it is in function also?

Comment: When you use an incorrect prototype (`()`), the solution isn't to add `&` to sub calls to override the prototype, it's to remove the incorrect prototype. Don't use prototypes, and don't use `&` on sub calls.

Comment: Which version of Perl are you using (and on which platform)?  The first print gives me `1` not `1.0` with Perl 5.16.2 on Mac OS X 10.7.5.  The second print, in the function, is consistent with the first, therefore (for me).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffer, It doesn't produce a warning because he explicitly overrode the prototype. If you remove the prototype override (`&`), you get `main::printvariable() called too early to check prototype`. Two wrongs don't make a right.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, `"$variable\n"` will give the same value no matter where it's called on all versions of Perl.

Comment: @ikegami: I've withdrawn my comment about prototypes...I should not be answering Perl questions tonight.  The OP claims to get `1.0` from the first print; you're saying it can never happen and I'm making the much less stringent claim 'it does not happen for me with my Perl'.  It is, however, relevant to ask the OP to verify which version of Perl on which platform produces the `1.0` answer — with there being a distinct possibility that in fact the OP's version of Perl does not produce `1.0`.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, If the OP's version of Perl produces `1.0`, then it produces `1.0` for both snippets. He claims he's only getting `1.0` from one snippet. I was explaining to you that this is impossible. `"$variable\n"` is `"$variable\n"`, no matter what you do with the returned value. (fyi, there's no build of Perl that will print `1.0` for either of those snippets.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you said isn't true.

```
$ perl -e'my $variable=1.0; print "$variable\n";'
1
```

`$variable=1.0;`, `$variable=1;` and `$variable= 4-3;` all assign the number *one* to `$variable`, and interpolation stringifies *one* to `1`. It has no way to know the code that produced the value was `1.0` or `4-3`, nor should that be important.

If you want to display a decimal point, either assign the three-character string `1.0` to `$variable`

```
$ perl -e'my $variable = "1.0"; print "$variable\n";'
1.0
```

Or convert the number to that string.

```
$ perl -e'my $variable = 1.0; printf "%.1f\n", $variable;'
1.0
```